# How to show current stock price instead of yesterday's close price

Tags: yahoo-api, yahoo-finance, stockquotes

I am using this [http://community.rightpoint.com/blogs/viewpoint/archive/2014/02/25/how-to-display-stock-information-in-sharepoint-2013.asp](http://community.rightpoint.com/blogs/viewpoint/archive/2014/02/25/how-to-display-stock-information-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx)x to display stock price on our sharepoint site. However, for past few days it only displaying the day before closing price. Any idea how to go by fixing the issue?

I am sorry if I am not being in complaint with SO. Please let me know if I need to improve any part of body.

Comment: The code is good. I think Yahoo is not updating in real time. I was able to test the select query here https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/ with this query select Symbol,Name,DaysLow,DaysHigh,YearLow,YearHigh,LastTradePriceOnly,LastTradeDate,LastTradeTime,MarketCapitalization,Change_PercentChange from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol = "MSFT" and it gave me yesterday's closing price.